# How do I determine a value for a rating on Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic2, rating, ionic3

Hey guys I know how do add a value for an rating on Ionic 2, put I need to display the same value on another page.

```
<h4> Value {{rating.star}} </h4>

<rating readOnly="true" max="5" emptyStarIconName="star-outline" halfStarIconName="star-half" starIconName="star" nullable="false"> </rating>
```

I need to put the value 'rating.star' in this rating. I'm using this import.

```
import { Ionic2RatingModule } from 'ionic2-rating';]
```

How can I do that? I've got a list of opinions and I do need to show them this value as others have evaluated, using this rating. Thanks for all.

Comment: You can create a service (create an Injectable with methods to get and set this rating value) and inject it in the components you need, or use a storage (like Native Storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://github.com/andrucz/ionic2-rating), you can set the value of the rating component by binding the property from your component with `ngModel`:

```
<h4> Value {{rating.star}} </h4>
<rating [(ngModel)]="rating.star" ...> </rating>
```

Comment: Ok, I thought I could only use this in a form. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, no, since it gets the value with `ngModel` you can bind that rating component to any property from your (component's) page... Glad to hear that it worked :)